# How to minimize parent window and show normal child window from c++?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

How to minimize parent window and show normal child window from c++, when is true that every time you minimize parent window the child window automatically minimize with them. For example in Visual studio 2010 I want to see only floating .cpp text editor (where is source code), and that rest of program be minimize (icons, menu, solution explorer,...), or hidden. What function to use, what steps to solve problem. 
OS win 7, 64.

EDIT: Coding in Win32.

Comment: C++ is kind of irrelevant here. What is relevant is whether or not you are using a framework or coding against raw Win32. Could you tell us?

Comment: When you say child window, I don't think that's the right term. Child is a special term. For example, a child window does not have caption bar, chrome etc. and is typically contained within its parent. I think you are talking about two top-level windows, one of which is owned by another. Typically the main form will be the owner. When a top level window is minimised, its owned windows will be minimized too. You need to create a window that is not owned by the main form. When you create an unowned window it will appear on the taskbar. Probably that's a good thing.

Comment: "You need to create a window that is not owned by the main form" - if I understand you as well you are talking about process when is creating application (own application) and then put those, ... but here is question how to handle to other existing windows and put non top window on top.

Comment: I don't understand the question. If you want the window to be unowned pass `NULL` as `hWndParent` when calling `CreateWindow`.

Comment: Yes but i dont Create my own window, I just want to handle to existing like using the FindWindow function, something like this HWND findw = FindWindowA("MsiDialogCloseClass", 0);

Comment: By following the instructions in my previous comment.

Comment: You can't do anything about the ownership rules. Owned windows will be minimized when their owners minimize. Owned windows will always appear on top of their owners. And ownership is determined when the window is created. It cannot be changed later. So you need to make the change in the call to CreateWindow.

Comment: Read all about it here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632599(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Actually, owned windows are _hidden_, not minimized, when the owner minimizes. So when the main window minimizes, windows owned by windows owned by it are kept on the screen.